# Angular 9 window scroll not working in internet explorer

Tags: angular, internet-explorer

```js
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', e => console.log('scroll'))
  }
```

[here is a stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-urgjck)

zone-flags.ts:

```js
(window as any).__Zone_disable_requestAnimationFrame = true; 
(window as any).__Zone_disable_on_property = true;
(window as any).__zone_symbol__UNPATCHED_EVENTS = ['scroll', 'mousemove'];
(window as any).__Zone_enable_cross_context_check = true;
```

My polyfill.ts:

```
import './zone-flags';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.
```

Yet no console log coming from ie 11.

This is a regression as Angular 7 had this working.

Comment: I see that you also opened issue on Angular github, its worth to link it there: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35781

Comment: One red flag I see is that support for the "scroll" event in IE11 is "unknown" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event I would also note that you shouldn't be binding your events in `ngAfterViewInit`. That things gets called A LOT of times. Just throw a `console.log` message in there and watch.

Comment: @mwilson As I stated, this is a regression from Angular 7, so support was there. Also `ngAfterViewInit` is called once during the life of the component.

Comment: Did you try to check and find the difference in your Angular7 and angular9 app? for testing purposes, try to keep your project similar to the old one.

Comment: @s.Lawrenz, Is the issue resolved or still persist? I can see in Github discussion that another user had posted the working demo. If the issue is solved, I suggest you post the solution here and mark your own answer. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.